# Copy directory using ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

The following command is working as expected.

```
ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 'cat test.txt'" > /home/shantanu/test.txt
```

What I need to do is to copy the entire directory instead of a single file.

Is it possible to use rync with SSH tunneling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe tar.

eg.

```
ssh soak@10.10.10.11 "ssh soak@10.199.199.191 'tar cf - test_directory'" | tar xf -
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `scp` to copy single or multiple files and also use `rsync` with an ssh transport:

```
scp -r localdirectoryname username@hostname:/remotepath
```

and

```
rsync -av localdirectory username@hostname:/remotepath
```

Both programs also work the other way round, with the remote part as the origin and the local as the destination.

See `man scp` and `man rsync`.

**Edit**

If you indeed need an intermediate server, you could use ssh port forwarding:

In one shell, use this command to establish a port forwarding:

```
ssh -NL 10022:10.199.199.91:22 soak@10.10.10.11
```

This connects port 10022 on your local machine with port 22 on `10.199.199.91`, but won't open a shell, instead just blocks until you terminate it.

Afterwards, on another shell/xterm, you can use either

```
scp -r -P 10022 localpath soak@localhost:/remotepath
```

but have to be aware that `soak@localhost` actually points to `soak@10.199.199.191` when entering your credentials.

**Edit 2, now featuring rsync**

As you specifically asked about rsync, here is how to use rsync instead of scp. It requires the same port forwarding enabled as the `scp` variant:

```
rsync -av --rsh="ssh -p 10022" localpath soak@localhost:/remotepath
```

and again remember that you are actually connecting to `soak@10.199.199.191`.

Comment: Does it connect to the intermediate server before copying data to remote host?

Comment: Maybe you should describe your requirements a bit better, especially why you need an intermediate server. Anyway, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is use [SSH Port Forwarding](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html).

First, run the following command on your computer:

```
$ ssh -N -f -L 2302:10.199.199.191:22 soak@10.10.10.11
```

This allocated a socket to listen to port 2302 on localhost. Whenever a connection connect to this port, it will be forwarded to `10.199.199.191:22`.

So you can copy a folder on `10.199.199.191` to your machine with:

```
$ scp -r -P 2302 soak@localhost:/path/to/folder /path/to/destination/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Also available is ssh's ProxyCommand.

From [Undeadly](http://www.undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20070925181947):

```
Host internal.hostname.tld internal
  User          merdely
  HostName      internal.hostname.tld
  ProxyCommand  ssh merdely@gateway.hostname.tld nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```